# Why does my text not appear in pygame when it is clearly blitted onto the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

**Why does my text not appear? I am trying to make a program in which the text is shown above the image. In the program, I still see the image, but not the text.**

````
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
image1 = pygame.image.load('frog.gif')
image2 = pygame.image.load('frog.jpg')
pygame.display.set_caption('\'Dancing frog\'')
image1 = pygame.transform.scale(image1, (800, 800))
image2 = pygame.transform.scale(image2, (800, 800))
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
text = font.render('this should appear', True, (255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(text, [10, 10])

run = True
while run:
    screen.blit(image1, (0, -200))
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    screen.blit(image2, (0, -200))
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.2)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False       
pygame.quit() ```
````

Comment: Likely `image1` and `image2` are draw over the text.

Comment: Unrelated but you should only call `pygame.display.update()` once. At the end after you have _blitted_ everything. It will cause flickering otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You must `blit` the text *Surface* after the bbackgorund image:

```py
screen.blit(image1, (0, -200))
screen.blit(text, [10, 10])
pygame.display.update()
```